# What is the part called that chainsaw bar flange nuts screw into?

Tags: chainsaw

I have a Ryobi RY3716 chainsaw. I lost a bar flange nut and replaced it with a non-Ryobi part (something like [this one](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Poulan-Pro-Chainsaw-Chain-Saw-Bar-Nuts/3653183)).

The new nuts didn't fit exactly, but I forced them on, causing damage. Now I can't remove them without removing the bolt they screw onto. I want to replace the nuts and the bolt with Ryobi parts, but I can't figure out what the bolts are called.

The parts manual is [here](https://www.gardnerinc.com/manuals/pdf/ipl/RYOBI/RY3714%20and%20RY3716%20%20090180501%20and%20090180502/RY3714_RY3716_090180501_090180502_499_r_01_2.19_.16_.pdf). The flange nut is 678339003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are generally called "bar bolts". These bolts are often *pressed* into the chain saw housing from the back side, it can be a complicated repair requiring significant disassembly of the saw.

Also, I do not see them on the parts diagram. This doesn't mean they are not available, but to find out you would have to call Ryobi customer service and explain what you need.

[check out this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0FjETX5FUDE)

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find them in the parts diagram, and thought I was going mad. I've actually removed one damaged one already -- rotating the flange nut actually rotates the entire bolt instead, because the threads are jammed. So replacing them should be straightforward. I hope.

Comment: Yeah, your problem is not uncommon with homeowner type saws. The bolts are often pressed into a plastic recess molded into the housing, so repeated over tightening (or cross-threading the bolt; like yours) can "round out" the recess, causing the bolt to spin. My point here is this: even with new bolts, if the housing recess is damaged the bolt will likely still spin. You may need to devise an alternative way to ensure the bolt is secure (2-part epoxy, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

They are bar bolts. They are in back side housing.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. You've added a number of answers, and that's great, but we're looking for a single best answer, and what you say here (and in other answers) is already in a better and more detailed answer. You should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.